# Python os.startfile stopped working in ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a little script that runs every day by cron and has been working for the last 3 months.

On 30th September it stopped working with the following error:

> File "NumberChecker.py", line 32, in start_server
>       os.startfile(startfile[0])
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

here is the code for that bit:

```
def start_server(xml):
    startfile = xml.xpath('/config/files/startfile/text()')
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    except:
        print('no server')
        server_status = 'down'
        os.startfile(startfile[0])
        while server_status == 'down':
            try :
                driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
                driver.get('http://www.google.com')
                server_status = 'running'
            except :
                pass
```

It just tests to see if the selenium server is up or not by requesting google and if not calls a bash script that starts it.

Why would os.startfile suddenly stop working?

I have tried at the command line this:

```
import os
os.startfile(home/adam/file/start_server.sh)
```

and I get

> File "< stdin >", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

I just can't work out why it has just stopped working?

It is python 3.3 in an virtual environment and the os is ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: Is it possible that `os.startfile` never worked, but September 30 is the first day that the exception handler was invoked?

Comment: Remove the exception handling. It has clearly never worked, and only hides the real error.

Comment: The program uses selenium which has to have the server running or it'll fail so I can't see how it could have never been through that code before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.startfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) is a Windows specific method, it won't work on linux.

Comment: Everything I read agrees with you. I don't know how it worked until now. What is the linux equivalent?

Comment: subprocess.Popen() seems to be the one to use